# request data from api with bearer token and refresh token

Tags: python, api, bearer-token

I am still a beginner at web scraping, I am trying to extract data from an API but the problem is that it has a Bearer token and this token changed after 5 to 6 hours so I have to go to the web page again and copy the token again so is there any way to extract the data without any more opening to the web page and copy the token again

I found this info as well on the network request, as someone told me that I could use the refresh_token to access but I don't know how to do that

Cache-Control: no-cache,
Connection: keep-alive,
Content-Length: 177,
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8,
Cookie: dhh_token=; refresh_token=; _hurrier_session=81556f54bf555a952d1a7f780766b028,
dnt: 1

````
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep


def make_request():
    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJMdXRiZlZRUVZhWlpmNTNJbGxhaXFDY3BCVTNyaGtqZiIsInN1YiI6MzEzMTcwLCJleHAiOjE2MjQzMjU2NDcsInJvbCI6ImRpc3BhdGNoZXIiLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJodXJyaWVyLmRpc3BhdGNoZXIiLCJjb2QuY29kX21hbmFnZXIiXSwibmFtIjoiRXNsYW0gWmVmdGF3eSIsImVtYSI6ImV6ZWZ0YXd5QHRhbGFiYXQuY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJlemVmdGF3eUB0YWxhYmF0LmNvbSIsImNvdW50cmllcyI6WyJrdyIsImJoIiwicWEiLCJhZSIsImVnIiwib20iLCJqbyIsInEyIiwiazMiXX0.XYykBij-jaiIS_2tdqKFIfYGfw0uS0rKmcOTSHor8Nk',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Origin': 'url',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Referer': 'url',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ar-EG;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7',
        'dnt': '1',
    }

    
    data = {
        'status': 'picked'
    }
    response = requests.post('url/api', headers=headers, json=data)
    print(response.text)

    return json.loads(response.text)


def extract_data(row):
    data_row = {
        'order_id': row['order']['code'],
        'deedline': row['order']['deadline'].split('.')[0],
        'picked_at': row['picked_at'].split('.')[0],
        'picked_by': row['picked_by'],
        'processed_at': row['processed_at'],
        'type': row['type']
    }
    return data_row



def periodique_extract(delay):
    extract_count = 0
    while True:
        extract_count += 1
        data = make_request()
        if extract_count == 1 :
            df = pd.DataFrame([extract_data(row) for row in data['data']])
            df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\di\Desktop\New folder\a.csv", mode='a')
        else:
            df = pd.DataFrame([extract_data(row) for row in data['data']])
            df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\di\Desktop\New folder\a.csv", mode='a',header=False)
        print('exracting data {} times'.format(extract_count))
        sleep(delay)


periodique_extract(60)

#note: as the website is track live operation so I extract data every 1 min ```
````

Comment: first scrape the token , then compose header and make request to the site. also keep checking for any change in token, if it changed then update it in your header. and do add the url here

Comment: Please post the URL you are trying to scrape. Are you getting the token as part of response headers ?

Comment: No i copy and past it from network request page @Ram

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these tokens require JavaScript execution to be set and automatically added to API requests. That means you need to open the page in something that actually runs the javascript, in order to get the token. I.e. actually opening the page in a browser.

One solution could be to use something like Selenium or Puppeteer to open the page whenever the token expires to get a new token, that you then feed to your script. But this depends on the specifics on the page, without a link the correct solution is difficult to say. But if the method of you opening the page in your browser, copying the token, then running your script works, then this is very likely to also work.